# Transposing in a specific order using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
    EmpID   Obs_ID  Component   Rating  avg_2a  avg_2d  avg_3b  avg_3c  avg_3d
    01301   13943   2a          3       3.0     3.0     1.0     1.33    1.0 
    01301   13944   2a          3       3.0     3.0     1.0     1.33    1.0 
    01301   13945   2a          3       3.0     3.0     1.0     1.33    1.0     
    01301   13945   2d          3       3.0     3.0     1.0     1.33    1.0     
    01301   13945   3b          3       3.0     3.0     1.0     1.33    1.0
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
        EmpID   comp_2a_obs_1 comp_2a_obs_2 comp_2a_obs_3 comp_2d_obs_1 ... ... comp_2a_avg comp_2d_avg comp_3b_avg comp_3c_avg comp_3d_avg
        01301   3             3             3             3             ... ... 3.0         3.0          1.0        1.33        1.0
```

Where the obs order (obs_1, obs_2, obs_3) is based on the `Obs_ID` (smallest to largest) and the value of the `comp_2a_obs_1`, etc columns are drawn from `Rating`

Can I do this with `pd.Transpose` or would I need a for loop or something else?

Comment: But all of your `Obs_ID` are equal.

Comment: @user3483203 fixed

Comment: Would be helpful to add the expected output as well.

Comment: @coldspeed done

Comment: Sounds like a job for pivot